# AWS Lambda Layers - Import numpy module works in one AWS account but not another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, import, aws-lambda-layers

I have access to two AWS environments - one is my own company's sandbox environment, and the other is a GovCloud environment for an agency that I support.

My team and I have been having issues in successfully importing Python modules using Lambda layers in the latter environment, but have no issues in the former. I've tried with a variety of runtimes and .zip file structures, but continue to encounter errors (usually an `Unable to import module` error).

I have followed the documentation to create the appropriate .zip file (in my test case, including just pandas) and then created the layer with this file and selected all Python runtimes. I've tried installing/zipping the packages on my local Windows machine and also within a Linux environment using WSL. In my company's sandbox environment, the `import pandas` lines works just fine, but for some reason the exact same layer in the other environment keeps throwing a module not found error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "36e2f9dc-0e18-4d85-bc7d-899c0fd3b2d8",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

My .zip file structure is as follows:

```
pandas-layer.zip
|___ python/
      |___ lib/
            |___ python3.10/
                  |___ site-packages/
```

I've also tried with having the contents directly in just the `python` directory, in which case I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

As a note, there are some older layers that previous team members have created for other modules that currently do work, so it doesn't seem as though its across the board, but at least for the last several weeks none of our new layers have been working. I also tried downloading an existing working layer and creating a new layer using the downloaded .zip and again ran into the same error (`Unable to import module...`).

Looking for any pointers on what could be the underlying issue. Curious if there are some IAM/permissions factors in play under the hood, though I myself don't have any permissions to see just about anything in IAM.

Appreciate any help!

**Edit:**

See my comments below, but part of the issue I was able to resolve due to different versions of Python between my Lambda runtime and the source of the layer. I updated the title of the question to specifically try and figure out why the `numpy` import (as a dependency of `pandas`) is giving the error above.

Comment: So after a bunch of troubleshooting, I realized some of my attempts were failing because I packaged the layer from Python 3.10 with the hierarchy `python/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, but was running in Lambda with 3.9 as the runtime. If I package them instead in just the `python/` folder, then technically most imports are working fine.

However, there seems to be a specific issue with libraries like `numpy` that are causing issues that I haven't been able to figure out. Another colleague was able to get `pandas`/`numpy` to work in 3.7, so the version may have something to do with it.

Comment: ^and as an example, the issue related to `numpy` to which I'm referring is the one about not importing from its source directory that I mentioned in the original question.